# Problem with package installation from GitHub

Tags: r, github, installation

I tried to install a package from GitHub, and I used the following code in `R`:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("Displayr/flipPlots")
```

But I obtained the following Error:

```
 Error: Failed to install 'flipPlots' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'flipTransformations' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'flipFormat' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'formattable' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘Rcpp’
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit.** After the suggestions enclosed in comments, I done the following steps:

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

but I obtained:

```
Error: Failed to install 'flipPlots' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'flipTransformations' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'flipFormat' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'formattable' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
```

Then:

```
install.packages("rlang")
```

and

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘backports’
```

Lastly I installed `backports` package but obtaining the following new error:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
 cannot open URL 
'https://api.github.com/repos/Displayr/flipPlots/contents/DESCRIPTION?ref=master'
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. I found that it solved itself when I manually installed `Rcpp` again and ran `install_github()` in a clean session. I also found that it would find other packages where this was the case and I just repeated the above until I was able to install the package from Github.

Comment: I fixed the problem, thank you!